# Unable to get go.net/websocket working behind nginx

Tags: nginx, websocket, go

I'm having trouble getting go.net/websocket to work behind nginx. It works if the application is accessed directly but with nginx, I get an EOF error from Receive.

What am I doing wrong?

Nginx version: 1.5.10

This is my nginx configuration.

```
location /wstest/ {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:7415/;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade "websocket";
    proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
    proxy_buffering off;
}
```

Go code:

```
func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", home)
    http.Handle("/sock", websocket.Handler(pingpong))

    http.ListenAndServe(":7415", nil)
}

func home(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    homeTmpl.Execute(w, nil)
}

func pingpong(conn *websocket.Conn) {
    var msg string
    if err := websocket.Message.Receive(conn, &msg); err != nil {
        log.Println("Error while receiving message:", err)
        return
    }

    if msg == "ping" {
        websocket.Message.Send(conn, "pong")
    }
}

var homeTmpl = template.Must(template.New("home").Parse(`
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>WS Test</title>
<script>
    var path = window.location.pathname;
    var wsURL = "ws://" + window.location.host +  path.substring(0,   path.lastIndexOf('/')) + "/sock";
    var ws;

    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
        ws = new WebSocket(wsURL);
        ws.onopen = function() {
        ws.send("ping");
    };

    ws.onmessage = function(event) {
        document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "Received: " + String(event.data);
    };
})
</script>
</head>
<body>
<span id="status">Pinging...</span>
</body>
</html>`))
```

Comment: Without testing your config, the only thing I can suggest is changing "Upgrade" to "upgrade" in `proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";`. It's possible it's case sensitive (although according to https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6455 it shouldn't be). You may also want to add the `Host` header with `proxy_set_header Host $host;` but I'm not sure it's required. See http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/websocket.html for an example.

Comment: Actually, according to https://code.google.com/p/go/source/browse/websocket/hybi.go?repo=net#428 the websocket package isn't case sensitive, so the problem shouldn't be with the headers. Will try to replicate the problem.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is the configuration that I'm using, it's working OK:

```
server {
    listen 0.0.0.0:20007;    
    index index.html;

     root /full/path/to/site;

    # pass the request to the node.js server with the correct headers 
    location / {

      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

      proxy_pass http://your_app/;
      proxy_redirect off;

      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }
 }
```

Comment: Changing `proxy_set_header Upgrade "websocket";` to `proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;` worked.

Comment: Thanks, settings `proxy_set_header Host $http_host;` helped in my case. Why isn't it on nginx example of configuration websockets proxy?